# How do I insert my own values in Windrose.py?

Tags: python, matplotlib, qgis

I have discovered [this](http://youarealegend.blogspot.fr/2008/09/windrose.html) module that works great, I love the output.
I am trying to change the values of the random input, here:

```
ws = random(500)*6
wd = random(500)*360
```

From [this reference](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/windrose/) we learn that

> This example uses randoms values for wind speed and direction(ws and wd variables). In situation, these variables are loaded with reals values (1-D array), from a database or directly from a text file (see the “load” facility from the matplotlib.pylab interface for that).

With my code, I've created two lists :

```
angles = [v1, v2, v3...] # values that replace wd
length = [v1, v2, v3...] # values that replace ws
```

These are the ways I've tried so far that don't work :

```
wd=np.array(angles)
wx=np.array(length)

wd=np.asarray(angles)
...
wd=np.fromiter(angles)
...
All give the error : TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

To be sure I actually have arrays:

```
a = np.array(angles)
print type(a)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
print a.ndim
1
```

I've also tried replacing directly with values, found in a thread [here.](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.matplotlib.general/9088/focus=9139), with the same results (list not callable)
So I am replacing random() by a given array, but Qgis still returns a 'list' error.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Try this example and check values in lists `angles` and `length`, they have to be float or integer:

```
from windrose import WindroseAxes
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from numpy.random import random
from numpy import arange, array

angles = [10.,20,40.,100.]
length = [1.,2.,3.,10]

ws = array(length)
wd = array(angles)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8), dpi=80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='w')
rect = [0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8]
ax = WindroseAxes(fig, rect, axisbg='w')
fig.add_axes(ax)

ax.bar(wd, ws, normed=True, opening=0.8, edgecolor='white')
plt.show()
```

[image]